# If $A^3=0$ show that $A^2=0$ (using Groebner basis)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, groebner-basis

> Let $A$ be a $2\times 2$ matrix such that $A^3=0$. Using Groebner basis show that $A^2=0$.

Any ideas on that?

Comment: Why would we use Groebner basis for this?

Comment: I know that there are a lot of easier methods to prove that. It's just an practice excercise on groebner basis

Answer (score 0):

This is very straightforward. Write 
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \cr c & d \end{pmatrix}
$$
and compute $A^2$ and $A^3$. The equations for $A^3=0$ imply the ones for $A^2=0$ via a Groebner basis. Indeed, the equations for $A^3=0$ are
\begin{align*}
0 & = a^3 + 2abc + bcd \\
0 & = b(a^2 + ad + bc + d^2)\\
0 & = c(a^2 + ad + bc + d^2)\\
0 & = abc + 2bcd + d^3
\end{align*}

The reduced Groebner basis here gives either $c=-a^2/b, d=-a$ or $b=d=a=0$ and $c$ arbitrary. That is, $A^2=0$.

Comment: Given the degrees, I would expect that what actually happens is that some *powers* of the elements of $A^2$ are in the ideal generated by the elements of $A^3$.

Comment: I obtain what is requested, so why the downvote?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter.

Comment: In fact, if my Maxima calculations are correct, $(a^2+bc)^3, (ab+bd)^3, (ac+cd)^3, (bc+d^2)^3$ are in the ideal generated by the formal elements of $A^3$.